# How do call the controller and action from javascript in Zend framework

Tags: zend-framework

How do  call the Controller/action  in Zend framework from Javascript  such as 
if(a==b){
}
else{
   document.myform.action="/fz/controllername/actionname"
}

My controllers are located in the src/controllers/

Answer (score 1):

Since a JS Call is just a regular web call you do it the same way you would access any other Action of your Project, the question is how you handle the output.

Answer (score 0):

Just call it like any other urls. If I had a news controller and wanted to post there from a form I would just set the form`s action to: '/news' and be done with it.

To expand on this a bit if I had a post action in my news controller I would set

```
if(a==b){ } else{ document.myform.action="/news/post" }
```

Comment: Dont we need extension as php

Comment: What? aaah. no not at all. In a Zf app everything goes thru index.php and the right controller with the right view are called.

Comment: Also you might want to look up modrewrite and routing in zend framework to help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
f(a==b){ } 
    else{ 
         document.myform.action="/controllername/actionname" 
    }
```